# how to zoom/pan automatically to all features in a vector layer?

Tags: zooming, openlayers, pan

Using Openlayers, I would like to initialize the map in a position where it shows all the features in a vector layer. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little sharp/rough

```
map.zoomToExtent(yourVectorLayer.getDataExtent());
```

This may be smoother

```
map.panTo(yourVectorLayer.getDataExtent().getCenterLonLat());
map.zoomTo(yourVectorLayer.getDataExtent().getZoomExtent());
```

Answer (score 1):

With OpenLayers `5.3.3` I use this code snippet:

```
const extent = vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent();
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```